# PHP strip query string so it doesn't return it to the user

Tags: php

I have a .NET MVC application on one server which I post a form to from a PHP page running on a different server. The app then redirects back to the original PHP script page.

That site is then returned to the client. Simple enough.

However, on the redirect (ASP.NET side), I send a query string to check for in the php code and in the browser the query string is displayed.

How can I first get the query string value (there is only one) and then remove it so when the page is returned to the browser it doesn't show the query string because it contains information I don't want the user to see.

I have tried

```
<?php unset($_GET['token']); ?>
```

without success. I have also tried a redirect using

```
header('Location: ... ')
```

but of course that just redirects and the new PHP file doesn't have the initial query string to perform that action.

I have also read about redirecting to a form with hidden values and autosubmit via javascript and if necessary I can use that, but it seems so wrong to go back to the client to send me back to the exact same php script just to strip the query string from the url.

I cant use an ajax post to the asp.net page due to CORS so I can't do that either.

Is what I am trying to achieve other than the javascript method possible?

Comment: Why don't you just use POST?

Comment: @Riet - apart from tweaking Wordpress sites, I don't really do PHP so I'm not quite sure what you mean. - Thanks for the comment though.

Comment: `$_GET` is just one way to pass a form. There is an equivalent `$_POST` method which is specifically designed to not show data like that to the user. `<form action="example.php" method="post">` would turn the request into a post request

Answer (score 0):

You can use .htaccess to remove all or specific GET parameter(s) from your URL

**Removing the Query String**

Delete the query string entirely.

```
RewriteRule ^/page /page?
```

**Remove a Single Key/Value**

To remove a single key/value pair from the query string. This example extends the above one by matching any value and removes multiple, consecutive '&' characters.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  (.*)(?:^|&)unWantedKey=(?:[^&]*)((?:&|$).*)
RewriteCond %1%2 (^|&)([^&].*|$)
RewriteRule ^(/path)$ $1?%2
```

So in your case `unWantedKey` = `token`

Reference: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString

Comment: Thanks for this. Not understanding PHP very much, will this remove the query string value for every page, or can I limit it to just one page.

Comment: yes you can limit it to just one page something like `RewriteRule ^/page1.php /page1.php?`

Comment: should "path" be replaced with a url or is supposed to be an actual url or php page

Comment: if `http://example.com/segment-1/segment-2` then `/path` = `/segment-2` or `/segment-1/segment-2`